# Proof Verification - $Y \subset K$ closed in K iff closed in X

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space with $K \subset X$ compact. Prove $Y \subset K$ is closed in K if and only if Y is closed in X.

Proof: (<=)
Assume Y is closed in K. Then, $K \backslash Y$ is open in K.
Since K is compact, it is closed in X. Therefore, $X \backslash K$ is open.
Then the complement of Y in X is $X\backslash K \cup K\backslash Y$.
Since both are open, $Y^{C}$ must be open in X. Thus, Y is closed in X. $\square$

Is this proof of the backward direction correct? I was a little lost on where to begin with this one, so it may need heavy revision or even a completely different strategy. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I do not agree that $K\setminus Y$ is open in $K$ implies $K\setminus Y$ is open in $X$. For example, $[1,2)=(0,2) \cap [1,3]$ is open in $[1,3]$ but not in $\mathbb{R}$. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

According to Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, the backward direction (<=) is immediately by definition of relative topology. (Indeed, $Y=Y\cap K$, where $Y$ is closed in $X$)

On the other hand, it needs some explanation. Since $Y$ is a closed subset in the compact set $K$, $Y$ is also compact in $Y$ and hence in $X$ (See Theorem 2.33 in Rudin's book). Thus, $Y$ is closed in $X$. The direction is then verified.